# Crear matriz a partir de bloques de la matriz original (Python)

Tags: python, matrices

El objetivo es crear una "*matriz mascara*" a partir de una matriz conocida de números reales con dimensiones *[H x W]*.

La  *matriz máscara* estará compuesta de `BLOCK_SIZES`, donde cada *BLOCK_SIZE* será de dimensiones `BSxBS`. Las dimensiones de la *matriz máscara* serán de `[BS x n·BS]` donde *n = Nº de BLOCK_SIZES*.

Supongamos que se tiene la siguiente matriz:

```
    |5 0 0 0 2 0 0 0|
    |0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|
    |0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0|
A = |0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0|
    |0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|
    |0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0|
    |0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|
    |0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8|
```

La nueva matriz que se desea es:

```
B = |5 0  2 0  0 0  3 0  0 0  0 0|
    |0 0  0 0  0 4  0 0  0 6  0 8|
```

Donde se aprecia que se han cogido bloques con `N = 2` y al menos uno de sus elementos es no nulo (*condición de bloque no nulo*), entendiendo como nulo el 0 a la hora de realizar el producto matricial.

El código que yo tengo recorre la matriz original y crea una máscara con ceros y unos en función de si el bloque obtenido cumple la *condición de bloque no nulo*:

```
def split(array, nrows, ncols):
    r,  h  = array.shape
    r_, h_ = int(r / nrows), int(h / ncols)
    mask = np.zeros((r_, h_))
    for i in range(r_):
        for j in range(h_):
            if np.sum(array[nrows*i:nrows*(i+1), 
                            ncols*j:ncols*(j+1)]) != 0:
                mask[i, j] = 1
    return mask
```

La matriz máscara sería (Con el mismo algoritmo puedo generar facilmente la matriz `B`):

```
       |1 0 1 0|
mask = |1 1 0 0|
       |0 1 0 0|
       |0 0 0 1|
```

El problema de mi método es que es tremendamente ineficaz, y como entrada (sin exagerar) tengo matrices de *16000x17000* y dimensiones similares o mayores.

Es posible realizar esto mediante matrices dispersas, como podría hacer lo mas eficiente posible este algoritmo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que todo funciona lo más rápido posible, lo suyo seria calcular todo con operaciones de numpy, sin emplear bucles explícitos.

Dependiendo si se quiere quitar o no los elementos que faltan para que las dimensiones sean un múltiple del `BLOCK_SIZES`, se puede añadir ceros (`np.pad`) o quitar los elementos que sobran (*slicing*).

Con `a.reshape(r_, nrows, c_, ncols)` se puede convertir la matriz en un conjunto de submatrices.

`np.count_nonzero` puede contar cuantos elementos hay que no sean ceros. Los ejes 1 y 3 forman las submatrices.  Convirtiendo el resultado en *bool* convierte cada cero en *False* y los otros números en *True*. Aunque no es recomendado, se puede convertir esos en ceros y unos con `astype(np.int)`.

Ejemplo de código:

```
import numpy as np

def create_mask(a, nrows, ncols, pad_with_zeros=False):
    r, c = a.shape
    if pad_with_zeros:
        r_, c_ = int(np.ceil(r / nrows)), int(np.ceil(c / ncols))
        a = np.pad(a, ((0, r - r_ * nrows), (0, c - c_ * ncols)))  # añadir ceros para que cada submatriz sea igual
    else:
        r_, c_ = r // nrows, c // ncols
        a = a[:r_ * nrows, :c_ * ncols]  # quitar los últimos elementos para que cada submatriz sea igual
    a = a.reshape(r_, nrows, c_, ncols)
    return np.count_nonzero(a, axis=(1,3)).astype(np.bool).astype(np.int)

N = 8
cnt = 10
a = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=np.int)
ind = np.random.randint(0, N-1, cnt*2).reshape(-1,2)
a[ind[:,0], ind[:,1] ] = np.arange(1, cnt+1, dtype=np.int)
print(a)
print(create_mask(a, 2, 2))
```

Ejemplo de resultado:

```
[[ 5  0  0  0 10  0  0  0]
 [ 9  0  0  2  0  6  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 8  0  7  4  0  0  3  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]
[[1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

Para calcular directamente la matriz B, el código seria un poco diferente:

```py
import numpy as np

def comprime_matrix(a, nrows, ncols, pad_with_zeros=False):
    r, c = a.shape
    if pad_with_zeros:
        r_, c_ = int(np.ceil(r / nrows)), int(np.ceil(c / ncols))
        a = np.pad(a, ((0, r - r_ * nrows), (0, c - c_ * ncols)))  # añadir ceros para que cada submatriz sea igual
    else:
        r_, c_ = r // nrows, c // ncols
        a = a[:r_ * nrows, :c_ * ncols]  # quitar los últimos elementos para que cada submatriz sea igual
    a = np.vstack(np.swapaxes(a.reshape(r_, nrows, c_, ncols), 1, 2))
    return a[np.count_nonzero(a, axis=(1, 2)).astype(np.bool)].swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(2, -1)

N = 8
cnt = 10
a = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=np.int)
ind = np.random.randint(0, N-1, cnt*2).reshape(-1,2)
a[ind[:,0], ind[:,1] ] = np.arange(1, cnt+1, dtype=np.int)

print(a)
print(comprime_matrix(a, 2, 2))
```

Ejemplo de resultado:

```
[[ 0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0]
 [ 2  0  0  0  0  1  0  0]
 [ 4  0  0  0  3  0  7  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  8  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  9  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]
[[ 0  0  0 10  0  0  4  0  3  0  7  0  9  0  0  6]
 [ 2  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]
```

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por la rápida respuesta. Modifiqué la pregunta pero se me olvido comentarte, gracias por avisar que estaba planteada de forma consfusa, en mi cabeza sonada todo bien hehe. 

Funcionan a la perfección los métodos y son mucho mas rápidos en comparación con el inicial que había propuesto. No he realizado aun medidas concretas, pero se aprecia considerablemente ;) .

Aun así, creo que voy a intentar aproximar el problema mediante matrices dispersas, puesto que sigue teninendo un coste computacional alto dependiendo de la entrada que se tenga.

Comment: El paso de añadir o quitar columnas/filas se puede evitar cuando ya son múltiples. `vstack`y `swapaxes` pueden tardar, no sé si hay posibilidad de evitarlos organizando el input de otra manera. El `reshape` es una operación instantánea, no depende de los tamaños.